# Trying to toggle a Redux boolean on a button click, however the toggle only works the first time and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a very simple redux slice that has 2 reducers which toggle a boolean to either on or off and a function inside of a hook that dispatches these actions depending on the current `forceToggle` state. By default `forceToggle` is `false`, so the first click should change `forceToggle` to `true`.

When I click the button for the first time, `forceToggleOn` gets dispatched which changes `forceToggle` to `true` which is what I expect.

The problem is that if I click that button again, I expect that `forceToggleOff` would get dispatched because `forceToggle` is `true` and change `forceToggle` to false, but this does not happen anymore. Only the first toggle works.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export type ToggleState = {
    forceToggle: boolean;
};

const initialState: ToggleState = {
    forceToggle: false,
};

export const toggleSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'activity',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        forceToggleOn: (state) => {
            state.forceToggle = true;
        },
        forceToggleOff: (state) => {
            state.forceToggle = false;
        },
    },
});

export const { actions: toggleActions, reducer: toggleReducer } = toggleSlice;
```

The function that gets called on button click:

```
const test = () => {
    forceToggle ? dispatch(forceToggleOff()) : dispatch(forceToggleOn());
};
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `useCallback` so it updates when `forceNativeActivities` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
const toggleForceNativeActivities = useCallback(() => {
    forceNativeActivities ? dispatch(toggleForceNativeActivitiesOff()) : dispatch(toggleForceNativeActivitiesOn());
    setItem(PERSISTED_FORCED_ACTIVITY_KEY, forceNativeActivities.toString());
}, [forceNativeActivities]);
```

Your handler is working with a stale value without `useCallback`.